# How do I change the colours of radio buttons, adding in multiple colours in radio buttons

Tags: css

I want to be able to change my radio button colours but not simply only one colour but three different colours...

I want 1, 2 and 3 to be red.. 4 to be orange and 5 to be green...

I have this coding:

```
/* Option 1 */
input[type='radio'] {   -webkit-appearance:none;   width:20px;   height:20px;   border:1px solid red;   border-radius:50%;   outline:none;   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px red inset; }

input[type='radio']:hover {   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px red inset; }

input[type='radio']:before {   content:'';   display:block;   width:60%;   height:60%;   margin: 20% auto;       border-radius:50%;  } input[type='radio']:checked:before {   background:red; }

/* Option 2 */
input[type='radio'] {   -webkit-appearance:none;   width:20px;   height:20px;   border:1px solid red;   border-radius:50%;   outline:none;   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px red inset; }

input[type='radio']:hover {   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px red inset; }

input[type='radio']:before {   content:'';   display:block;   width:60%;   height:60%;   margin: 20% auto;       border-radius:50%;  } input[type='radio']:checked:before {   background:red; }

/* Option 3 */
input[type='radio'] {   -webkit-appearance:none;   width:20px;   height:20px;   border:1px solid red;   border-radius:50%;   outline:none;   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px red inset; }

input[type='radio']:hover {   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px red inset; }

input[type='radio']:before {   content:'';   display:block;   width:60%;   height:60%;   margin: 20% auto;       border-radius:50%;  } input[type='radio']:checked:before {   background:red; }

/* Option 4 */
input[type='radio'] {   -webkit-appearance:none;   width:20px;   height:20px;   border:1px solid orange;   border-radius:50%;   outline:none;   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset; }

input[type='radio']:hover {   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset; }

input[type='radio']:before {   content:'';   display:block;   width:60%;   height:60%;   margin: 20% auto;       border-radius:50%;  } input[type='radio']:checked:before {   background:orange; }

/* Option 5 */
input[type='radio'] {   -webkit-appearance:none;   width:20px;   height:20px;   border:1px solid green;   border-radius:50%;   outline:none;   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px green inset; }

input[type='radio']:hover {   box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px green inset; }

input[type='radio']:before {   content:'';   display:block;   width:60%;   height:60%;   margin: 20% auto;       border-radius:50%;  } input[type='radio']:checked:before {   background:green; }
```

But it does not seem to change all the colours... Just makes all of them green...?

Comment: what is language programming?? Please more explain.

Comment: you should use classes for your approach, at the moment you overwrite everything (the first three ones) with the last one, which is green

Answer (score 3):

You have to go for CSS classes. To get this working, you have to edit your html like this:

```
<input type='radio' class='red' />
<input type='radio' class='red' />
<input type='radio' class='red' />
<input type='radio' class='orange' />
<input type='radio' class='green' />
```

and your css looks like:

```css
    .green,
    .red,
    .orange {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border: 1px solid green;
      border-radius: 50%;
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px green inset;
    }
    .red {
      border: 1px solid red;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px red inset;
    }
    .orange {
      border: 1px solid orange;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
    }
    .green:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px green inset;
    }
    .red:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px red inset;
    }
    .orange:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
    }
    .green:before,
    .red:before,
    .orange:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 60%;
      height: 60%;
      margin: 20% auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .green:checked:before {
      background: green;
    }
    .orange:checked:before {
      background: orange;
    }
    .red:checked:before {
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<input type='radio' class='red' name='custom' />
<input type='radio' class='red' name='custom' />
<input type='radio' class='red' name='custom' />
<input type='radio' class='orange' name='custom' />
<input type='radio' class='green' name='custom' />
```